# Should the variable value be checked before assigning?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I know this might sound like a silly question but I'm curious should I check my variable value before assigning?

like for example if I'm flipping my `skin` (Node2D composed of sprite & raycast) based on direction (Vector2) :

```
func _process(delta):
    ...

    if(direction.x>0):
        skin.scale.x=1
    elif(direction.x<0):
        skin.scale.x=-1
  
   #OR


    if(direction.x>0):
        if(skin.scale.x!=1):
           skin.scale.x=1
    elif(direction.x<0):
        if(skin.scale.x!=-1):
           skin.scale.x=-1
```

would the skin scale be altered every _process hence consuming more CPU usage
**OR**
if the value is same will it be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, given that this is GDScript, so the number of lines will be a performance factor.

We will look at the C++ side…

---

But before that… Be aware that GDScript does some trickery with properties.

When you say `skin.scale` Godot will call `get_scale` on the `skin` object, which returns a `Vector2`. And `Vector2` is a value type. That `Vector2` is not the scale that the object has, but a copy, an snapshot of the value. So, in virtually any other language `skin.scale.x=1` is modifying the `Vector2` and would have no effect on the scale of the object. Meaning that you should do this:

```
skin.scale = Vector2(skin.scale.x + 1, skin.scale.y)
```

Or this:

```
var skin_scale = skin.scale
skin_scale.x += 1
skin.scale = skin_scale
```

*Which I bet people using C# would find familiar.*

But you don't need to do that in GDScript. Godot will call `set_scale`, which is what most people expect. It is a feature!

---

So, you set `scale`, and Godot will call `set_scale`:

```
void Node2D::set_scale(const Size2 &p_scale) {
    if (_xform_dirty) {
        ((Node2D *)this)->_update_xform_values();
    }
    _scale = p_scale;
    // Avoid having 0 scale values, can lead to errors in physics and rendering.
    if (Math::is_zero_approx(_scale.x)) {
        _scale.x = CMP_EPSILON;
    }
    if (Math::is_zero_approx(_scale.y)) {
        _scale.y = CMP_EPSILON;
    }
    _update_transform();
    _change_notify("scale");
}
```

*The method `_change_notify` only does something in the editor. It is the Godot 3.x instrumentation for undo/redo et.al.*

And `set_scale` will call `_update_transform`:

```
void Node2D::_update_transform() {
    _mat.set_rotation_and_scale(angle, _scale);
    _mat.elements[2] = pos;

    VisualServer::get_singleton()->canvas_item_set_transform(get_canvas_item(), _mat);

    if (!is_inside_tree()) {
        return;
    }

    _notify_transform();
}
```

Which, as you can see, will update the `Transform2D` of the `Node2D` (`_mat`). Then it is off to the `VisualServer`.

And then to `_notify_transform`. Which is what propagates the change in the scene tree. It is also what calls `notification(NOTIFICATION_LOCAL_TRANSFORM_CHANGED)` if you have enabled it with `set_notify_transform`. It looks like this (this is from "canvas_item.h"):

```
    _FORCE_INLINE_ void _notify_transform() {
        if (!is_inside_tree()) {
            return;
        }
        _notify_transform(this);
        if (!block_transform_notify && notify_local_transform) {
            notification(NOTIFICATION_LOCAL_TRANSFORM_CHANGED);
        }
    }
```

And you can see it delegates to another `_notify_transform` that looks like this (this is from "canvas_item.cpp"):

```
void CanvasItem::_notify_transform(CanvasItem *p_node) {
    /* This check exists to avoid re-propagating the transform
     * notification down the tree on dirty nodes. It provides
     * optimization by avoiding redundancy (nodes are dirty, will get the
     * notification anyway).
     */

    if (/*p_node->xform_change.in_list() &&*/ p_node->global_invalid) {
        return; //nothing to do
    }

    p_node->global_invalid = true;

    if (p_node->notify_transform && !p_node->xform_change.in_list()) {
        if (!p_node->block_transform_notify) {
            if (p_node->is_inside_tree()) {
                get_tree()->xform_change_list.add(&p_node->xform_change);
            }
        }
    }

    for (CanvasItem *ci : p_node->children_items) {
        if (ci->top_level) {
            continue;
        }
        _notify_transform(ci);
    }
}
```

So, no. There is no check to ignore the change if the value is the same.

However, it is worth noting that Godot invalidates the global transform instead of computing it right away (`global_invalid`). This is does not make multiple updates to the transform in the same frame free, but it makes them cheaper than otherwise.

---

I also remind you that looking at the source code is no replacement for using a profiler.

Should you check? Perhaps… If there are many children that need to be updated the extra lines are likely cheap enough. If in doubt: measure with a profiler.